VBA Text Colour Checking Error with Seeing Yellow
I'm working on a semi-automatic rota for my work; I am new to VBA but have other coding experience.
There is a 'written table rota,' where the start and end times of everyone is inputted, and the shift type is colour coordinated by text colour. And a 'visualiser' that outputs a visual schedule of when everyone is due in for the day.
I've made quite a lengthy if block for checking the text colour in the written table rota (Range("I" & table_row_number)), with the intention of then colour-coordinating the visualiser to be the same colour (except for when the text is black - that would output a grey colour in the visualiser).
Every part of it works as intended, except for the final 'elseif' to check for 'gym check yellow' - it instead outputs an error message. I have absolutely no idea what is different between the other if statements and this one, since all the other statements work as intended and are seemingly identical in wording and style.
I have omitted the selection definition as it is unnecessary for the problem and would require me to define a lot more variables that are also not related to the problem, but to summarise, the selection is the range of cells that represents their shift in the visualiser. I know that the selection is working as intended as it highlights the correct cells.
For table_row_number = 6 To 100 Step 2

If Range("I" & table_row_number).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
        Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(165, 165, 165)
        ' Make the visualiser time-block bar grey (since black would be too bold)

  ElseIf Range("I" & table_row_number).Font.Color = RGB(68, 114, 196) Then
        Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(68, 114, 196)
        ' Make the visualiser time-block reception blue

  ElseIf Range("I" & table_row_number).Font.Color = RGB(112, 173, 71) Then
        Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(112, 173, 71)
        ' Make the visualiser time-block park cafe green

  ElseIf Range("I" & table_row_number).Font.Color = RGB(237, 125, 49) Then
        Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(237, 125, 49)
        ' Make the visualiser time-block padel shack orange

  ElseIf Range("I" & table_row_number).Font.Color = RGB(225, 192, 0) Then
        Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
        ' Make the visualiser time-block gym check yellow
        MsgBox "Gym Check Yellow"

  Else
        MsgBox "Error"
End If
Next

Thank you for reading and if anyone has any ideas on what is making yellow behave differently I would greatly appreciate the assistance <3

"an error message" doesn't tell us much...

In the last condition you have RGB(225, 192, 0) and RGB(255, 192, 0). Are they correct?

Sorry Tim, by error message I mean that it outputs the "error" message box instead of the "gym check yellow"

Hi MGonet, you are absolutely right. They're both supposed to be 255, that's why it wasn't reading. That's quite an embarrassing problem to not notice sooner so thank you for proofreading for me!

If you only need to remap a single color then this would be less repetitive.
    Dim clrIn As Long, clrOut As Long
    
    For table_row_number = 6 To 100 Step 2
        'next line really needs a specific worksheet reference...
        clrIn = Range("I" & table_row_number).Font.Color
        Select Case clrIn
            Case RGB(0, 0, 0)
                clrOut = RGB(165, 165, 165) 'grey (since black would be too bold)
            Case RGB(68, 114, 196), RGB(112, 173, 71), _
                 RGB(237, 125, 49), RGB(255, 192, 0)
                clrOut = clrIn 'same color for non-black
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Unknown color"
                clrOut = -1
        End Select
        If clrOut <> -1 Then Selection.Interior.Color = clrOut
    
    Next

FYI most likely you don't need to use Selection here, but without the rest of your code it's difficult to suggest exactly how to replace it.

Thank you Tim! Yes there are definitely better ways to go about this than what I've thought up but I don't know enough about VBA language to be fully optimal. Once I've got a working first iteration I will look into implementing your suggestion so streamline the code. Thanks again!

I misread the RGB code, so whilst my code isn't optimal it is now working as intended with the correct RGB numbers.
For table_row_number = 6 To 100 Step 2 

If Range("I" & table_row_number).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
    Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(165, 165, 165)
    ' Make the visualiser time-block bar grey (since black would be too bold)

  ElseIf Range("I" & table_row_number).Font.Color = RGB(68, 114, 196) Then
    Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(68, 114, 196)
    ' Make the visualiser time-block reception blue

ElseIf Range("I" & table_row_number).Font.Color = RGB(112, 173, 71) Then
    Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(112, 173, 71)
    ' Make the visualiser time-block park cafe green

  ElseIf Range("I" & table_row_number).Font.Color = RGB(237, 125, 49) Then
    Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(237, 125, 49)
    ' Make the visualiser time-block padel shack orange

  ElseIf Range("I" & table_row_number).Font.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) Then
''' Correction to above RGB value, 225 -> 255 
    Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) 
    ' Make the visualiser time-block gym check yellow
    MsgBox "Gym Check Yellow"

  Else
    MsgBox "Error"
End If
Next

Thank you to everyone that assisted <3
